# Flow Meter connected RPI 3 wiring

Tags: power, wiring, pi-3b+

Is the wiring the same from a RPI B+ to a RPI 3 to connect a the flow meter too? If you strip the connector to just bare ends from the flow meter what cables/connectors do you recommend purchasing for that? Then I am assuming in my application for my Brewpi I can configure the script for the flow meter on there. My intent is for the flow meter to defined volume then have a valve turn off so I get a fairly consistent water level every time. - thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all the Pis with the 40 pin expansion header have the same connections.

Use any connectors you find convenient.